# Calling a google script web app from a service account

Tags: google-apps-script, service-accounts

I have a basic `doGet` function taken from google's documentation:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);
}
```

I've deployed it as a standalone Web App, given it permissions to be accessed by anyone from the organization, and managed to call it from the browser successfully using a URL like:
`https://script.google.com/a/macros/**/s/some-guid/exec?a=b`:

```json
{"parameters":{"a":["b"]},"contextPath":"","contentLength":-1,"queryString":"a=b","parameter":{"a":"b"}}
```

However, when I try to call it programmatically using a service account, I get a `401`:

```
    creds, project = google.auth.default()
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    creds.refresh(auth_req)
    print(creds.valid)  # prints True

    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + creds.token}

    response = requests.get("THE_ABOVE_URL" , headers=headers)
    print(response)  # prints `401`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you specify the parameters when calling programmatically?

Comment: Also: did oyu deploy the WebApp runnign as you or the user accessing the WebApp?

Comment: I deployed the web app as running as myself.

Comment: Did I specify which parameters? The GET call works without specifying any parameters. When I'm in the browser it simply uses my authentication so it works.

Comment: In this case, you need to deploy it as "Who can access": "Anyone, even anonymous" and - very important: the applicaiton from where you make a call to the WebApp needs to have a Drive scope.

Comment: Can't I have it: anyone, within the organization?

Comment: Not if you access it programamtically. Mind that  no one who does not know your deployment URL will be able to deploy your WebApp.